# Increase size of font-awesome

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the following code in my JSP file , My question is how to increase the size of the font-awesome inside  ?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div style="text-align: left;" class="span3 row-fluid">
                <label><spring:message code="alert.channels.outbound.lines"></spring:message>:&nbsp; </label>
                </div>

            <div class = "span3">
            <div class="textbox">  
             <div class="textVal">${alertStatusForm.outboundLines}</div> 
                <div class="pencil span3 ">
                <i class="icon-edit"></i>
                 </div>
                <div class="save span3">
                 <i class= "icon-save"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="close span3">
                <i class= "icon-folder-close"></i>
                </div>
            </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#larger-icons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to target the particular class you are trying to change and then tweak the font size. This looks like bootstrap so there should be some icon-large, icon-small, icon-medium classes you can include on your i class value.

Alternately, you can pin point your class value and manipulate it directly.

```
.icon-folder-close { font-size:100%;}
.icon-folder-close {font-size:20px;}
```

Depends on how the rest of your code is setup.